# Calling a template in loop (XSLT 2.0)

Tags: xml, templates

Assume that we are dealing with XSLT 2.0.

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book name="history_123" attr1="HIST.123" attr2="history_123_new" attr3="1">
    <chapter name="history_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="history_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="history_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="history_123_666"/>
  </book>
  <book name="geography_123" attr1="GEO.123" attr2="geography_123_new" attr3="1">
    <chapter name="geography_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="geography_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="geography_123_666"/>
  </book>

  <book name="chemistry" attr1="CHEM.123" attr2="chemistry_123_new" attr3="1">
    <chapter name="chemistry_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="chemistry_123_666"/>
    <chapter name="chemistry_123_666"/>
  </book>

</books>
```

I am applying the following xsl sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="book[starts-with(@attr1, 'HIST')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace_attributes">
      <xsl:with-param name="attr1Value" select="'123'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'hist'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book[starts-with(@attr1, 'GEO')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace_attributes">
      <xsl:with-param name="attr1Value" select="'456'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'geo'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book[starts-with(@attr1, 'CHEM')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace_attributes">
      <xsl:with-param name="attr1Value" select="'678'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'chem'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace_attributes">
    <xsl:param name="attr1Value" />
    <xsl:param name="prefix"/>
    MATCH <xsl:value-of select="$attr1Value"/>
    MATCH <xsl:value-of select="@attr1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice I have to call the template 3 times with different values of the parameters attr1Value and prefix. How can I use collections and loop so I can compact the code and call the template function once in a loop for different values of attr1Value and prefix?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure the of collections is necessary here. Can you give us a clue on how it is possible to compute the attribute values from the input XML? Thanks.

Comment: assume that the attribute values are known. You can assume that we can create three parameters. param1 = GEO, param2 = 456 and param3 = geo for the first template-match call. I would like to remove the almost duplicate calls after the first one and use parameters to implement that.